# Wait for File Processing to be finished

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring Integration to process/load data from csv files.
My Configuration is -

1) Poll For incoming File

2) Split the file using splitter - this gives me individual lines(records) of the file

3) Tokenize the line - this gives me the values or columns

4) Use aggregator to aggregate/collect lines(records) and write it to database in a batch

Poller -> Splitter -> Tokenizer -> Aggregator

Now I want to wait till all the content of the file has been written to the database and then move the file to a different folder.
But how to identify when the file processing is finished ?

Problem here is, if the file has 1 million records and my aggregator has batch size of 500, how would i know when every record of my file has been aggregated and written out to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileSplitter` can optionally add markers (BOF, EOF) to the output - you would have to filter and/or route them before your secondary splitter.

See [FileSplitter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/files.html#file-splitter).

> 3. (markers) Set to true to emit start/end of file marker messages before and after the file data. Markers are messages with `FileSplitter.FileMarker` payloads (with START and END values in the mark property). Markers might be used when sequentially processing files in a downstream flow where some lines are filtered. They enable the downstream processing to know when a file has been completely processed. In addition, a header `file_marker` containing START or END are added to these messages. The END marker includes a line count. If the file is empty, only START and END markers are emitted with 0 as the lineCount. Default: `false`. When true, `apply-sequence` is false by default. Also see `markers-json`.

Comment: This would only work in sequential processing of the file, but i am processing the file in parallel